# finding largest of 5 numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Need to find the largest of a series of numbers, but the numbers must come from user input. For this assignment the JavaScript must be written in HTML doc, this is what I have so far:

```js
function getLargest(a,b,c,d,e){
  let numArray = [b,c,d,e];
  let largest = a;

  for(let item of numArray){
    if(item > largest){
      largest = item;
    }
  }
  return largest;
  document.getElementById('largest').innerHTML = largest
}
let a = prompt("Enter 1st Number");
let b = prompt("Enter 2nd Number");
let c = prompt("Enter 3rd Number");
let d = prompt("Enter 4th Number");
let e = prompt("Enter 5th Number");

getLargest (a,b,c,d,e);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h2>The Largest number is:</h2> 
    <p id = "largest"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Math.max`, maybe?

Comment: The problem with your attempt is, that you return before you display the result, and discard the returned value...

Comment: You can also use `arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)`

Comment: @FZs could you expound on that ?

Comment: @Archies but that would create an *unnecessary overhead* (= would be slower)...

Comment: On which? `Math.max` or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code returns `largest` before it gets to `document.getElementById('largest').innerHTML = largest`.

Additionally, you can just use `Math.max(...numArray)` to get the maximum instead of all the code you have to find `largest`.

Answer (score 2):

you could write the getLargest function like this:

```js
function getLargest(...nums) {
  let max_value = Math.max(...nums);
  return max_value;
}
```

Comment: Or even more simply, `const getLargest = Math.max`... Or... just calling `Math.max` instead of `getLargest`...